# How to use pipe on observable data?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a component that subscribes to a CartService that holds shopping cart items.  What I'd like to do is use a pipe to calculate the cart total based on the contents & display the value.

**How do I iterate over my observable data to calculate/return the total?**  Right now when I log out the value going into my pipe it's just return the observable not the data.  What gives?

```
//calculateTotal.pipe.ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from "lodash";

@Pipe({name: 'calculateTotal'})
export class CalculateTotal implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: string): any {

    _.each(items, function(item){
      console.log(item);
    })

    return items;

  }
}



// nav-cart.component.pug
{{items | calculateTotal}}




//nav-cart.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


import { StoreItem } from '../../store.item.interface'
import { CartService } from '../../services/cart.service'


@Component({
  selector: 'nav-cart-component',
  styleUrls:['nav-cart.component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'nav-cart.component.pug',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native  // Use the native Shadow DOM to encapsulate our CSS

})
export class NavCartComponent {

  cartItems:StoreItem[] = [];

  items: StoreItem[] ;
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) {

    cartService.cartList$.subscribe(
      res => {
        this.items = res;
      })



  }

}
```

Comment: Chain it with the `async` pipe: `{{ items | async | calculateTotal }}`.

Answer (score 0):

You property `items` isn't a observable. I don't know your service, will it return a array back, or maybe its JSON? It should work if everything goes right..

```js
cartService.cartList$.subscribe(
   res => {
      console.log(res); // CHECK THIS.. VALID ARRAY?
      this.items = res;
   });
```

And change your pipe..

```
transform(items: ItemStore[]): any {
   console.log(items); // ARRAY HERE?
```

You are trying to subscribe that observable and put that items to a local property..

You could use that observable directly instead!
As @cartant commented already, you should use the `async`-pipe and then your `calculateTotal`-pipe.

```js
// COMPONENT

items: Observable<StoreItem[]>;

constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
   this.items = cartService.cartList$
}

// TEMPLATE

{{items | async | calculateTotal}}
```

You can chain as much pipes as you like.. you can use braces if you like:

```js
{{((items | async) | calculateTotal) | anyOtherPipe : 'with' : 'three' : 'paramteres'}}
```